# FabricJS: Always Center Object on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

is it possible to ALWAYS center an object on a fabricjs canvas?

Background: I am building a webtool that makes it easy to create complex animations using fabricjs. I want to be able to set the canvas size to 100% for both width and height. Thus I want to place all my objects at the center and add an X/Y offset to it. When I resize the canvas later on I can readjust the objects from center using the x/y offset.

Is there such a build in function? Or should I simply add a property to the object and if the canvas is being resized - check all objects for that property and readjust the object's position from the new canvas' center?

Regards and Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fabric objects have the following methods for centering:

```
obj.center();  // Centers object vertically and horizontally on canvas to which is was added last
obj.centerV(); // Centers object vertically on canvas to which it was added last
obj.centerH(); // Centers object horizontally on canvas to which it was added last
```

I don't see anything about offset in the docs.

Something like the following would probably work

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

$(window).resize(function(){

     var w = $(window).width();
     var h = $(window).height();
     var center = {x:w / 2, y:h / 2);

     canvas.setDimensions({width:w,height:h});
     canvas.forEachObject(function(obj){

        obj.set({
            left : center.x + obj.offsetLeft,
            top : center.y + + obj.offsetTop,
        });

        obj.setCoords();

    });

// need to call calcOffset whenever the canvas resizes
canvas.calcOffset();
canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: don't forget .setCoords() after center operation!

Answer (score 39):

Or you can center the object like so

```
    // add the image object 
    Canvas.add(oImg)
    // set the object to be centered to the Canvas
    Canvas.centerObject(oImg);

    Canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
    Canvas.renderAll();
```

Comment: After centering the image, you need to call `oImg.setCoords()` in order to move its coordinates to the right position. When you omit the call, the image is moved, but you need to click on its old position to interact with it.

Answer (score 0):

Since fabricjs 2.3.6 you can use [viewportCenterObject](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#viewportCenterObject)

```
fabric_canvas.setZoom(10)

fabric_canvas.viewportCenterObject(obj)
fabric_canvas.renderAll()
```

https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/pull/2021