# Centering Object with in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

Below is how I am arranging a circle in the canvas clip using Fabric JS.

```
   $(".arrangeHorizntal").click(function(){
    if(checkSelection()){           
        selectedObj.top = clipRectangle.top+clipRectangle.height/2;    
        selectedObj.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }

})
```

However when I am zooming the canvas It is not actually center and it is way off to the center. So my guess is that because of scaling.

How to handle it ? tried `centerObject` function, but that is for centering in canvas and not with in the rect. Any clues ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Center:

```
selectedObj.center();
```

Center horizontally:

```
selectedObj.centerH();
```

Center vertically:

```
selectedObj.centerV();
```

Comment: [I read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270168/fabricjs-always-center-object-on-canvas). But it centers to the canvas, not to the rectangle clip I have